# Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from standart JAR file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat6, jsp-tags

I'm facing a problem with a new project written with JSP.
Some details :
- Using tomcat6.
- Using Java Oracle 6.
- inteliji for development.

When depolying and running the app via Inteliji I get all the time this error :

```
 HTTP Status 500 - /login.jsp(1,63) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
```

I extracted the standart.jar inside the lib, and I do see the c.tld with the right uri specified in the jsp file.

Please your help resolving this issue.

Comment: You should just add JSTL jar to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Please use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I had used https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl and got same error.

Answer (score 0):

in your JSP write

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

in WEB.xml

```
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/jstl/c.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jstl/c.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
```

files in WEB-INF/jstl

[image]

file in WEB-INF/lib

[image]